# Simple algorithm exercise - inputs and loop

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, while-loop

"We want to calculate the amount to be paid by n consumers of electricity in a building. Write an algorithm that takes  the cost of kWhour, the number of customers, and the consumption in kWh of each customer. Present the amount to be paid by each of the consumers. Present the total to be paid monthly by all customers in the building."

Ok, we need 2 inputs (number of consumers + cost of consume - kw/hour).
Then, we need to calculate the individual consume and then the total consume, in a month.

Here's what i've got so far (nothing):

```
costkwh = (input("Type the cost of KhW: ")) #kwh cost

n = int(input("Type the number of consumers: ")) #number of consumer


while n > 0:
    consume = int(input('Type your Kw consume, in a month: '))
    consumemonthly = (consume*costkwh)
    print("Your monthly consume is ", consumemonthly)
```

Also, how should I do it with FOR loop?

It's my first week in programming so I apologize ya'll for this but its really frustrating... Thank you.

Comment: How would you imagine to do it by hand?

Comment: `costkwh = get ("Enter the cost of kwh in your region")
n = get ("Enter the number of residents in the building")

for x in range (N times), do:
consume = float(input('Type your Kw consume, in a month: '))
 consumemonthly = (consume*costkwh)
 write("Your monthly consume is ", consumemonthly)
 totalConsumption = totalConsumption + consumemonthly

write("The total consumption of the building is", totalConsumption)`

The thing is, I still feel that the individual consumption lacks substance regading its definitions and exibition (maybe ask for the number of apartment, dont know...)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by initializing a separate variable before the while loop and adding each consumer's consumemonthly to it.

```
    costkwh = (input("Type the cost of KhW: ")) #kwh cost

    n = int(input("Type the number of consumers: ")) #number of consumer

    totalConsumption = 0

    while n > 0:
        consume = int(input('Type your Kw consume, in a month: '))
        consumemonthly = (consume*costkwh)
        print("Your monthly consume is ", consumemonthly)
        totalConsumption = totalConsumption + consumemonthly

    print(totalConsumption)
```

If you choose to use a list instead you will need to loop over the list again to find the sum. But you will also retain each consumemonthly in the list just in case you want to do any other calculation based on that. Solution involving list will look like below:

```
costkwh = (input("Type the cost of KhW: ")) #kwh cost

n = int(input("Type the number of consumers: ")) #number of consumer

while n > 0:
    consume = int(input('Type your Kw consume, in a month: '))
    consumemonthly = (consume*costkwh)
    print("Your monthly consume is ", consumemonthly)
    consumemonthly_list.append(consumemonthly) 

total_consumption = 0

for ele in range(0, len(consumemonthly_list)):
    total_consumption = total_consumption + ele

print(total_consumption)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: not working... first, there was a string x int conflict, which I already fixed. but now, this "while n > 0" is the problem. It keeps running the code to infinity. I need a while that sees the value atributed to n and only asks these questions n number of times. thats why I tought on for _ in range (n).

Comment: Yes the n needs to be decremented inside the loop. With n= n-1 at the end of the loop.

Comment: I still feel that the individual consumption lacks substance regading its definitions and exibition (maybe ask for the number of residence on the input and display the individual consumption, by residence, on a list...) How would you do it?